# lm function throws an error in terms.formula() in R

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to run linear modelling on the training data frame, but it is not giving me the output.

It gives me an error saying

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
'.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Code

```
n <- ncol(training) 
input <- as.data.frame(training[,-n])
fit <- lm(training[,n] ~.,data = training[,-n])
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to remove the column from the data to perform this operation, and it's best to use names.

Say that your last column is called `response`.  Then run this:

```
lm(response ~ ., data=training)
```

It's hard to say that this is the formula that you need.  If you provide a reproducible example, that will become clear.